# Unified notification panel

Tags: feature-request

I would like to have a unified notification panel (top menu) where i can see messages, rep, and badge from all the sites of the network.
For example, I'm on meta, stackoverflow and serverfault, my panel should look like this:

```
Cesare | Meta: msg 0, rep 133, bedge 6 | Stack: msg 2, rep 552, bedge 9 | Server: msg 1, rep 120, bedge 3 | log out | about | faq | search
```

To be honest it's mostly about the messages and the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Firefox or Google Chrome, you're in luck! (As far as the reputation goes, anyways). I wrote [an extension for Google Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/google-chrome-sofu-aggregator-extension) that does just that:

[screenshot http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/4241/afterss.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/4241/afterss.png)

For Firefox, there's a [Greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/greasemonkey-script-to-show-profile-reputation-and-badges-from-all-so-sites-in) (which is what I based my extension off of).

I also personally recommend the [Stack Overflow Notifier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier) extension for Chrome - not mine, but way awesome. Unlike mine, it *will* show you notifications, replies, etc.

Comment: Should be better if it was native but, cleaver, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Boy, I bet you're happy about the [new "local inbox"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65625/replace-envelope-with-local-inbox/85258#85258).