# Replace envelope with "local inbox"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox

I really liked that inbox on the Stack Exchange icon. Since there are some bugs with the envelope, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61012/any-progress-with-the-envelope-indicator), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39301/envelope-lighting-up-arbitrarily-and-unpredictably), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/762/latency-of-the-red-envelope) and maybe on more places, I think it would be nice to change it a bit.

There could be an arrow pointing down, the same as in this image: [image: arrow]

It could open a window just like the Stack Exchange icon and have some tabs, like:

- responses
- favorites
- reputation

And a link somewhere that would lead to `/users/recent/`, where you can see everything.

- summary
- reputation
- responses
- favorites
- revisions
- badges

Perhaps the envelope icon could change to fit. The icon would continue redirecting to `/users/recent/` and the down arrow would open that nice window. The inbox would display only changes from the current site and indicate how many new things are out there. Just like the global inbox.

Well, it's just a thought. I think changing it "completely" would automatically fix the bugs and give a nice feature.

Comment: I *love* the inbox. The envelope's always felt buggy for me.

Comment: "Well, it's just a **premonition**", not *thought*. You forgot you dreamt about this in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed per

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of this idea, as long as the replacement of the envelope is site-specific. I like the way the inbox is working, but I don't like it that different sites are all thrown together. The added functionality would be nice.

But I don't know if rewriting the envelope would fix the bugs. As far as I understood from other discussions, the problem is essentially related to caching, both on the browser level and on the site level. And I don't know whether it would be possible to let that notification system work in real-time.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I suggested, a "local inbox". Thanks for supporting the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Being new to the site, I wanted to add that I automatically associated the envelope with the inbox, the fact that I couldn't access the notifications was confusing at first...