# View Recent stats link broken

Tags: support, stack-overflow, recent

I normally go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent to see new comments or messages. I have it bookmarked in the toolbar. As of today, the link no longer works. Any idea why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace envelope with "local inbox"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65625/replace-envelope-with-local-inbox)

Comment: At the very least, where is the new page that I can see comments to my comments that might not have a point impact.

Comment: If only you had 10k, you could see the giant argument at [Eeeek! What happened to my envelope?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82538/eeeek-what-happened-to-my-envelope). Per Jeff, "Forget the /recent pages. The /recent pages will be around as a safety blanket for a while, but we want to rebuild them -- better than they were before."

Answer (score 2):

The envelope that linked to the recent page was recently removed and replaced with the activity dropdown (hover over your username at the top of the screen to see it). Accordingly, as there is no other way to get to the recent page, it was deprecated and removed.

Comments and answers are available in the Global Inbox (upper left hand corner—the red number indicates new responses—click to see), and reputation and badges are in the activity dropdown.

For background:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/

Comment: The link was the easiest way to get to recent stats. I don't know why they keep changing things.

Comment: I can't seem to get the same information as users/recent using any other mechanisim.

Comment: yea same here. I don't understand why they had to disable the link.

Comment: @Hussein Why do you find the Global Inbox harder to use? In theory, since it lets you know about all SE sites at once, it should be easier to use.

Comment: @Chris What information are you looking for?

Comment: The traditional way is easier on the eyes and you can easily see what questions where accepted and which you got votes on.  Global inbox is annoying, you have to hover over it and wait till it loads, then everything squished in one small box.  Most of the times it doesn't update unless i refresh the page then hover over it again.